# Two objects pointing to same address is not working. e.g. newArray = oldArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-copy, shallow-copy, ios8.3

I am using the following type of object reference copy functionality throughout my iOS application.

e.g. `objectA = objectB;`

When you perform operation/changes on objectA it would automatically get reflected in objectB. You do not need to copy objectA to objectB again to reflect the changes in objectB, as they are pointing/referring to same location(address).

The problem is it was working fine till the iOS 8.2 however it seems to  not work in iOS 8.3 at all.

Following is one of the code snippet which is not working correctly.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *fieldObj = self.theData[indexPath.section ][indexPath.row];

    // Adding text to data array
    [fieldObj setObject:textField.text.stringByStrippingHTML forKey:@"value"];

    NSLog(@"Line 1 \n%@",fieldObj);
    NSLog(@"Line 2 \n%@",self.theData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]);
```

From Above code Line 1 and Line 2 are giving same output upto iOS 8.2.

```
Line 1 
  {
    name = Name;
    required = NO;
    type = 4;
    value = asdfasdfasdfasdfsad;
  }
Line 2 
  {
    name = Name;
    required = NO;
    type = 4;
    value = asdfasdfasdfasdfsad;
  }
```

however in iOS 8.3 they are giving the different outputs.

```
Line 1 
  {
    name = Name;
    required = NO;
    type = 4;
    value = asdfasdfasdfasdfsad;
  }
Line 2 
  {
    name = Name;
    required = NO;
    type = 4;
    value = "";
  }
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

If not does anyone know about the issue and how to solve it?

**EDIT:** 
Sorry for the above misleading question, the reason behind above problem I found is that the indexPathForItemAtPoint:(CGPoint) is returning wrong indexPath in iOS 8.3 only.

```
The code I have used is as follow:
// retrieve indexpath from uitextfield
    CGPoint pos = [textField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:pos];
```

The above code is working fine upto iOS versions 8.2.

Comment: The most common reason for that kind of thing is a latent bug in your code, that is a bug that for some reason didn't do anything noticeable in one OS version but gets noticed in another version. Did you check that you do indeed have the same objects? No other thread modifying theData?

Answer (score 2):

I made and easy snippet that I think it will reflect you actual situation: an immutable container with mutable container inside.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        NSArray * array = @[@{@"KEY" : @"OLD" }.mutableCopy];
        NSMutableDictionary * dict = array.firstObject;
        [dict setObject:@"NEW" forKey:@"KEY"];
        NSLog(@"Mutated dict %@",dict);
        NSLog(@"From original source %@",array.firstObject);



    }
    return 0;
}
```

Everything seems to work as expected, are you sure that you are doing something somewhere else?

> 2015-04-15 08:37:09.740 prova[912:117578] Mutated dict {
>       KEY = NEW; }
>  2015-04-15 08:37:09.741 prova[912:117578] From original source {
>       KEY = NEW; }

Also the both object have the same address as expected:

> (lldb) expression dict (__NSDictionaryM *) $2 = 0x00000001003004a0 1
>   key/value pair
>  (lldb) expression array.firstObject (__NSDictionaryM *)
>   $3 = 0x00000001003004a0 1 key/value pair

Comment: I think it is different issue, I am modifying object of index (0,1) but it is actually modifying the object at other index, strange. But I am sure it has to do with something iOS 8.3.

Comment: @ViruMax: I'm sure it has nothing to do with iOS 8.3 but everything to do with a bug in your code. The iron rule for fixing bugs: Believe that it is your bug. _You_ did something wrong. Find _what_ you did wrong. By fixating on OS 8.3 you'll never find it.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks for your help, I found the issue and it is iOS 8.3 specific. The issue is related to the function indexPathForItemAtPoint which is returning wrong indexPath in iOS 8.3 only.

Comment: That doesn't explain what you posted, so I assume that your initial code was actually a lie. And frankly I'd be curious why you would ever call indexPathForItemAtPoint. And you found _your_ latent bug: CGPointZero is not inside one view or another, it is right between two views, so your result was always undefined. Latent bug which bytes you on 8.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it as below.

```
NSMutableDictionary *fieldObj = 
[
     self.theData[indexPath.section ][indexPath.row]
     mutableCopy
];
```

& check. I believe it will work.

Comment: Ok I will check immediately, one question , so it is iOS 8.3 issue?

Comment: @ViruMax : I can't say..  I just noticed that object assign is working fine, however `self.theData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` data is changed...

Comment: In this case I think about Occam razor. It seems really unprobable that Apple has changed a behavior written in ObjC rules even a bug ;-). But if it is, is a huge issue.